# Javascript appendChild does not reflect in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to insert an image tag inside an iframe.
When I debug the code I can see the added html in the object. But it does not show up in the DOM nor can I see it on the page
This is a snippet for reference.

```
var tdForImage = iframewindow.document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
var imgTag = document.createElement("img");

//copying img src value from elsewhere
imgTag.src = iframewindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;

//Remove the wrongly placed second image.
iframewindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].parentNode.removeChild(iframewindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);
tdForImage.appendChild(imgTag);
```

After this I can see that there is no change in the UI. The iframe is BLANK. In its document there is nothing in the head nor in the body.
While debugging, I can see img inside innerHTML attr in tdForImage.
Why does the iframe get cleared?
If anyone has some experience of such issues please advise..

EDIT 1 >>
I have noticed that on IE 11, the script added to the iframes head tag is not loaded when the page is loaded for the first time.
This seems to be the root cause of the issue.
I have already tried adding a 2 second timeout.
I have already tried loading the script containing function as innerHTML.
Both are not working.
If anyone knows a way to force IE to load the scripts immediately after the appendChild call please let me know..

Comment: Hey @kavita can you please generate snippet for this

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya - It has too many dependencies. I have tried to put independent code here. Main point is that append child is replacing the iframe content with blank.

Comment: @kavita what is `iframewindow`?

Comment: var iframe = document.getElementById(frame); - iframe
 var iframewindow = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;

Comment: what is the content of the iframe? is it an external url? (same domain/different domain)

Comment: It is a string containing the content - scripts, html, style

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on JSFiddle:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

```
// Fill iframe for demo
document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.write('<table><tr><td>fdsafdsa</td></tr></table><img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" />');

var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

var iframewindow = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentDocument.document;
console.log(iframewindow.toString());

var tdForImage = iframewindow.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
var imgTag = document.createElement("img");

imgTag.src = iframewindow.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
iframewindow.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].parentNode.removeChild(iframewindow.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);

tdForImage.appendChild(imgTag);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r6o83gL5/12/

But if your iframe is on a different domain, you will not be allowed to access it's body.

Comment: This works fine on Chrome. Since the content is a string not a url there is no question of cross-domain

Comment: which browser causes your problem? im on a mac, chrome, firefox and safari works fine for me. (sorry, i can't test IE)